# How to revert the MUST_CHANGE in ALTER LOGIN SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say that someone executes the result from the select:

```
ALTER LOGIN [myLOGIN] WITH PASSWORD = 'myPassword' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_POLICY = ON;
```

How is the correct way to execute a new `ALTER LOGIN` statement, which removes the `MUST_CHANGE` policy? Is something like this ok or there is another better practice:

```
ALTER LOGIN [myLOGIN] WITH PASSWORD = 'myPassword' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

Comment: Take at look --> Understanding password policy for sql-server logins [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028712/understanding-password-policy-for-sql-server-logins)

Comment: @Fmanin - it is an interesting read, thanks, pity there is no SQL inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following this sentense:

> Set MUST_CHANGE for new logins. If MUST_CHANGE is specified, CHECK_EXPIRATION and CHECK_POLICY must be set to ON.

from  [PasswordPolicySQLServerLogin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028712/understanding-password-policy-for-sql-server-logins), the best practice should be like this:

```
ALTER LOGIN [myLOGIN] WITH PASSWORD = 'myPassword', CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to disable MUST_CHANGE and CHECK_POLICY is with 2 separate statements.

```
ALTER LOGIN [myLOGIN] WITH PASSWORD = 'myPassword';
ALTER LOGIN [myLOGIN] WITH CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

combining the answers above.  i used.

```
ALTER LOGIN [myLogin] WITH PASSWORD = '******' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_POLICY = ON, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON;
```